# How to configure karate afterScenario in karate-config.js file

Tags: karate

I am using Karate '* **configure** **afterScenario** = ' in feature file and **getting results successfully** and able to have DB calls as well. How to implement same in **Karate-config.js**?

Note: I have a Java class call as well.

Any implementation like this?

Code using in feature file

```
Background:
* def inFluxDb = Java.type('aPITests.InfluxDBCall');
* def dbCDB = new inFluxDb();
* configure afterScenario = 
"""
function(){
  var info = karate.info; 
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.scenarioName);
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.errorMessage);
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.featureDir);
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.featureFileName);
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.scenarioDescription);
  var featurenameupdate = info.featureFileName.substring(0, info.featureFileName.length-8);
  var status="Fail";
  if(!info.errorMessage){
  status="Pass";
  }
  dbCDB.DBConnection( "http://localhost:8086", "root", "root");
  dbCDB.DBwrite( featurenameupdate, info.scenarioName, info.errorMessage, status );
  dbCDB.connectionClose();
}
"""
```

**Update: Concern after using karate.configure**

Scenario: I have two feature files

Feature1: API) contains @smoke @test tags

Feature2: UI) contains @dropdown @Angular

My `* def configure afterScenario`is declared into Feature2 file
While executing only @smoke test, my `karate.configure('afterScenario', 'UI.feature');` is not loading.

is this as expected or else anything need to be updated from my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `karate.configure()` API to move any feature `configure` step into the JS config.

```
karate.configure('afterScenario', read('some.feature'));
```

I don't recommend "bloating" your `karate-config.js` unless absolutely necessary, because it is called for every `Scenario` or `Examples` row. Consider using a `ExecutionHook` instead.

Comment: After using karate.configure('afterScenario', read('some.feature')); i have a concern. Updated into original post. please Check 'Concern after using karate.configure' and let me know your valuable inputs.

Comment: @SandeepPadala sorry I don't understand. ask a new question. if it is not clear, you will have to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sorry Peter Thomas, i was asking like if i am loading my afterScenario from some.feature in karate-config.js and while executing my tests(with a specific tag which dont include some.feature scenario file tags). Unable to load afterScenario from some.feature while executing . Hope you got it.

Comment: @SandeepPadala of course if the `afterScenario` has not been configured, it will not work, I may be missing something, you know what to do now :)